# Filter by grandchildren count in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having difficulties constructing a query whereby `A` objects are filtered by `C` count, where `C` is a grandchild of `A`. This is my current (simplified) models code:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'as'
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bs'
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('as.pk')
    a = relationship('A', backref='bees')

class C(Base):
    __tablename = 'cs'
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bs.id'))
    child = relationship('B', backref='cees')
```

I've tried the following queries, without success:

```
DBSession.query(A).filter(func.count(A.bees.cees) == 5)
# Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated 
# with A.bees has an attribute 'cees'

DBSession.query(A).having(B.cees == 5)
# missing FROM-clause entry for table "bs"
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `subquery`:

```
sq = (session.query(A.pk.label('a_pk'), func.count(C.pk).label('num_cees'))
      .outerjoin(B).outerjoin(C).group_by(A.pk)
      .having(func.count(C.pk) == 5) # toggle-comment-line
      ).subquery('c_count')

q = (session.query(A)
     .join(sq, A.pk == sq.c.a_pk)
     # .filter(sq.c.num_cees == 5) # toggle-comment-line
     )
```

You can put the filter condition in either the `subquery` or the main `query`. Only be careful with the case of filtering for `0` (none) Cs in A.

Comment: Thanks @van, I've marked your answer as correct, as it technically is (the best kind of correct). In your answer you construct a `subquery` which is further from ORM code than I would have liked. Do you think there is a way of writing this query using only ORM and class properties, i.e. not using the pk's, outerjoins and group_by's?

Comment: I do not think that you can do this without `join`s (explicit or implicit). Event when you use `orm`, in the end `sql` statements are emitted and ran agains the database. If you have a more simple `SQL` that would achieve the desired result, please share it, and I am sure we will be able to translate it to as close to `ORM` as possible.