# SQLAlchemy: filter model object with deep relationships?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have three model objects with two one-to-many relationships:
`Match <-> Slot <-> Player`
Relationships are defined with backrefs `'player'` and `'match'`. So what I'm trying to do is find all matches that satisfy `match_filter` filter:

```
slot_filter = or_(Slot.account_id==None,
                  Slot.additional_units!=None)
                # func.count(Slot.player.slots)<=1)

match_filter = and_(Match.human_players==10,
                    Match.game_mode==2,
                   ~Match.slots.any(slot_filter)) 

query = session.query(Match).join(Slot)
query = query.filter(match_filter)
matches = query.all()
```

The problem is that I don't really know where should I add Player.slots in my query and how can I filter out matches in which at least one player has less (or equal) than n matches played. I already read something about `group_by`, `having`, and `func.count` methods, but I still don't understand how to use them in my case.

**Edit** I found almost the same question: [Filter by grandchildren count in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914494/filter-by-grandchildren-count-in-sqlalchemy)
But I still have not figure out how to apply this to my relationships

**Edit** Here is my solution:

```
subquery = session.query(Player.id).\
           join(Slot).\
           group_by(Player.id).\
           having(func.count(Player.slots) > 1).\
           subquery()

matches =  session.query(Match).\
           join(Slot).\
           join(Player).\
           filter(Player.id.in_(subquery)).\
           filter(match_filter).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: You have to think more like you are working within `SQL` and less like within an ORM.

If you want to filter by a grandparent, then - if working in `SQL` - you obviously would have to do a `JOIN` or use a sub-`SELECT`.

Having said that, filtering in `SQLAlchemy` is a very close match to doing a `SELECT` in pure `SQL`.

`HAVING` is something which only applies after your result-set has been generated by the RDBMS, so if your result-set is rather large, using `HAVING` will be very slow. So use with care.

As for the other options:

### Using `JOIN`

**Pro:**

- If you have to access joined objects through a `relationship` you can use this to pre-populate these objects using `joinedload`, etc.

**Con:**

- One thing to have in mind is that if you do a many-to-many `JOIN` then your result-set will of course multiply to have more rows. `SQLAlchemy` therefore will have to read more data (and possibly discard it). Depending on your data this can take a hit on performance.
- This is also the reason why you have to use `group_by` to arrive at a sane `count` again. Using `GROUP BY` is normally less performing than something which uses indices sanely.

### Using sub-SELECTs with `correlate`

These have to be written using SQLAlchemy-CORE. For example:

```
subselect = (select([Player.id])
            .select_from(Player.__table__.join(Slot.__table__)
            .where(Player.slot_id == Slot.id)
            .correlate(Slot.__table__))
```

This is not a dis-advantage. In fact, I prefer using SQLAlchemy this way, as I get more predictable performance out of my queries.

**Pro:**

- No performance hit like when using JOINs.

**Con:**

- No possibility to pre-load attributes on joined relationships.